# scikit-learn add training data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I was looking at the training data available in `sklearn` at [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html). As per documentation, it contains 20 classes of documents, based on some newsgroup collection. It does a fairly good job of classifying documents belonging to those categories. However, I need to add more articles for  categories, like cricket, football, nuclear physics, etc.

I have set of documents for each class ready, like `sports -> cricket`, `cooking -> French`, etc.. How do I add those documents and classes in `sklearn` so that the interface which now returns 20 classes will return those 20 plus the new ones as well? If there is some training that I need to do, either through `SVM` or `Naive Bayes`, where do I do it before adding it to the dataset?

Comment: could you please upload your code you have and where you are stuck?

Comment: I am not really stuck anywhere, there is no code to show! I just want to know how to add more training data (documents and accompanying class) to the 20 class of documents skilearn already provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your additional data has the following directory structure (if not, then this should be your first step, because it will make your life a lot easier as you can use the `sklearn` API to fetch the data, see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html)):

```
additional_data
      |
      |-> sports.cricket
                |
                |-> file1.txt
                |-> file2.txt
                |-> ...
      |
      |-> cooking.french
                |
                |-> file1.txt
                |-> ...
       ...
```

Moving to `python`, load up both datasets (supposing your additional data are in the above format and are rooted at `/path/to/additional_data`)

```
import os

from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import numpy as np

# Note if you have a pre-defined training/testing split in your additional data, you would merge them with the corresponding 'train' and 'test' subsets of 20news
news_data = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all')
additional_data = load_files(container_path='/path/to/additional_data', encoding='utf-8')

# Both data objects are of type `Bunch` and therefore can be relatively straightforwardly merged

# Merge the two data files
'''
The Bunch object contains the following attributes: `dict_keys(['target_names', 'description', 'DESCR', 'target', 'data', 'filenames'])`
The interesting ones for our purposes are 'data' and 'filenames'
'''
all_filenames = np.concatenate((news_data.filenames, additional_data.filenames)) # filenames is a numpy array
all_data = news_data.data + additional_data.data # data is a standard python list

merged_data_path = '/path/to/merged_data'

'''
The 20newsgroups data has a filename a la '/path/to/scikit_learn_data/20news_home/20news-bydate-test/rec.sport.hockey/54367'
So depending on whether you want to keep the sub directory structure of the train/test splits or not, 
you would either need the last 2 or 3 parts of the path
'''
for content, f in zip(all_data, all_filenames):
    # extract sub path
    sub_path, filename = f.split(os.sep)[-2:]

    # Create output directory if not exists
    p = os.path.join(merged_data_path, sub_path)
    if (not os.path.exists(p)):
        os.makedirs(p)

    # Write data to file
    with open(os.path.join(p, filename), 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.write(content)

# Now that everything is stored at `merged_data_path`, we can use `load_files` to fetch the dataset again, which now includes everything from 20newsgroups and your additional data
all_data = load_files(container_path=merged_data_path)

'''
all_data is yet another `Bunch` object:
    * `data` contains the data
    * `target_names` contains the label names
    * `target contains` the labels in numeric format
    * `filenames` contains the paths of each individual document

thus, running a classifier over the data is straightforward
'''
vec = CountVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(all_data.data)

# We want to create a train/test split for learning and evaluating a classifier (supposing we haven't created a pre-defined train/test split encoded in the directory structure)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, all_data.target, test_size=0.2)

# Create & fit the MNB model
mnb = MultinomialNB()
mnb.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluate Accuracy
y_predicted = mnb.predict(X_test)

print('Accuracy: {}'.format(accuracy_score(y_test, y_predicted)))

# Alternatively, the vectorisation and learning can be packaged into a pipeline and serialised for later use
pipeline = Pipeline([('vec', CountVectorizer()), ('mnb', MultinomialNB())])

# Run the vectorizer and train the classifier on all available data
pipeline.fit(all_data.data, all_data.target)

# Serialise the classifier to disk
joblib.dump(pipeline, '/path/to/model_zoo/mnb_pipeline.joblib')

# If you get some more data later on, you can deserialise the model and run them through the pipeline again
p = joblib.load('/path/to/model_zoo/mnb_pipeline.joblib')

docs_new = ['God is love', 'OpenGL on the GPU is fast']

y_predicted = p.predict(docs_new)
print('Predicted labels: {}'.format(np.array(all_data.target_names)[y_predicted]))
```

Comment: Wow. That looks very promising. Couple of questions - What do I do with the final `all_data` variable? I mean, this example - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html shows how to classify documents. How do I use the `all_date` obtained above in this case?

Secondly, the last part of your answer is a bit unclear to me, a little more explanation will be great.

Comment: @AttitudeMonger I've updated my answer - could you briefly explain which part was unclear?

Comment: Wow. It keeps on getting better and better! This deserves a bounty bigger than 50, I will award it more in future..:) Coming back, I can't understand, where above do I put my data to test it against the existing data set? Like for example, in the link I provided above, `docs_new = ['God is love', 'OpenGL on the GPU is fast']` loads the text data for which I want to find the matching categories. And for each text in the list, I get the result. How is it done above in your example?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger Do I understand correctly that you want to train a model on the existing 20newsgroups data and classify your new data?

Comment: Umm, no, no, not that. I have 20 existing categories. I want to add say 40 more categories, for each of which I will add corresponding documents. So now I have 60 categories. Any text for which I want to find the category, if it belongs to any of these 60 categories (which include the 40 new I have added), I should get the resultant category and its accuracy.

Comment: The first part of the code above merges the documents from the 20 existing categories with your new data with 40 categories, giving you the full 60. The  second part then trains a classifier on all the data (with 60 categories). If you want to classify any _other_ new data, you would need to serialise the learning pipeline (the vectorizer and the classifier in the example above) and then run any new documents through the pipeline to obtain their labels.

Comment: Well, that was precisely I had asked in the question - how to do that, so it would be great if you can add that to the answer as well - how to find out the category for a piece of text against those 60 categories.

Comment: @AttitudeMonger I've added examples for pipelines and serialisation/deserialisation - hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Ah, that is it.. I will take some time to create accurate data and add it to the existing data set to verify. But this looks promising. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more question - where are the default 20 newsgroup articles located on the hard disk? I feel there is more to it than just files containing raw text on a given category, I think it contains lots of other metadata as well, which I must replicate if I want to achieve similar levels of accuracy for the new categories.

Comment: by default `sklearn` stores the data under `~/scikit_learn_data` on OS X and Linux (no idea about Windows), so if you used `fetch_20newsgroups` to load the data then there will be a few pickle files starting with `20news-bydate...` in that folder. IIRC the directory structure encodes the category and whether it belongs to the train or test subset

Comment: I found a `pkz` file. How do I use it to get the content files? Unable to unzip it or untar it..

Comment: And the `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, all_data.target, test_size=0.2)` does this for each category I assume - take 20% of the documents in that category, and test them against the remaining 80% with the algorithm to see if it is a good fit?

Comment: You can check the [`sklearn` code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.py#L154) for fetching the 20 newsgroups data. And yes, I *think* `train_test_split` splits each category 80:20.

Comment: No no, I don't want to see the code to load the content. That is already well documented, plus you mentioned it clearly in your answer. I want to see in what format the text is stored in individual files, whether it is just raw text, or some JSON structure, or with headers and footers as metadata, etc..so that I can put the content in my new categories accordingly.

Comment: The `news_dara` obj should contain all data relevant to classification. `news_data.data` contains the raw text (utf-8 formatted iirc), consisting of the subject line and the message body as one string. `news_data.filenames` encodes some meta information, I'm not aware of any other metadata

Comment: Yes, so how can I get to see the actual text files where the raw text is stored?

Comment: its in the pickle files, you can read it using the `sklearn` API and then write it back to disk yourself. However the contents will be equivalent to whats stored in `news_data.data`

Comment: But the files have to be there physically somewhere on the disk, right? Where can I find them?

Comment: Yes, they are in the pickle files in the `scikit_learn_data` dir.

Comment: Yes, the `pkz` file, right? How do I open it to find the individual files inside? The directory you mention contains only one `pkz` file.

Comment: You can check the relevant section in the [sklearn code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.py#L154) for how the pickle file is loaded there, with the relevant code relating to loading and unpickling the content being in lines 209-213. If you want to download a tar archive to see the content of the individual files you can download it e.g. from [here](https://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/20newsgroups/20newsgroups.html)

Comment: Thanks. When I looked into the files, there's a problem. The contents of most files are very small emails, with a header and footer describing the sender and receiver. Whereas the documents I am putting are big articles, but very well representing the category. Also there is no header and footer (because they are no emails, say extract from a web article). Will that cause a problem or imbalance in the algorithm that runs over all articles combined, that 20 sets of documents are formatted like emails with little content, while the new ones are big articles with no headers and footers?

Comment: There's no definite answer to that question (completely up to empirical evaluation), however as long as the collective mass of documents represent the category reasonably well i would expect it to be fine. Many short documents should have the same representational power for a category as a smaller number of large documents.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking the same.. Most of the categories have like thousands of documents, so if the new categories contain 100 articles of substantially big size, that should be reasonably balanced, right? In fact, if that leads to better prediction for the new categories, I might as well replace the existing documents with more accurate and big sized articles, which can represent the categories much better.